# How to get the unicode of a character in Apache Velocity (VTL)

Tags: velocity, vtl, aws-appsync-resolver

Im trying to obtain the Unicode(code) of a character in VTL.
For example I would like to get the number 902 from the character `Ά`
The analogue in JS would be:

`'Ά'.charCodeAt(0)`

> `902`

Similarly the char code of a blank space would be 32:

`' '.charCodeAt(0)`

> 32

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the [Character.codePointAt(str, index)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#codePointAt-java.lang.CharSequence-int-) static method.

```
#macro(unicode, $chr)
  #set($str = "$chr")
  $str.charAt(0).codePointAt($str, 0)
#end

#unicode('Ά')
```

Explanation: in VTL we need (dummy) instances to call static methods. We first convert the argument to a string and call `charAt(0)` on it to get a Character instance, just to be able to call the `codePointAt()` static method on its first character.

This seems rather convoluted, alas the Java API is not so great here.